# Every time i append a string in for loop , i get a null in between

Tags: apex, visualforce, approval-process

So I am running a string append statement inside a for loop

```java
String apComment;
apComment = ''; 
for(Processinstancehistory p:lispros)
{
    apComment +=p.Comments;
}
```

So after this, I get the comments in below way

```
Comment1nullComment2Comment3
```

I get a `null` in between. Can someone please help how to remove this `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+Dan's response..

You can use null check before appending it to your string..

```
String apComment = ''; 
for(Processinstancehistory p:lispros)
{
    if (string.isNotBlank(p.Comments)) {
        apComment +=p.Comments;
    }
}
```

or you can create a list of comments and use string.join as suggested..

```
String apComment = '';
List<String> comments = new List<String>();
for(Processinstancehistory p:lispros)
{
    if (string.isNotBlank(p.Comments)) {
        comments.add(p.Comments);
    }
}

if (!comments.isEmpty()) {
    apComment = string.join(comments, ',');
}
```

Comment: it worked ,thank you . Also I am getting all the commments in 1 line . Do you know how can I apply line breaks here . '/n' is not working as I am displaying the comments in email template

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [String.join()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) instead of trying to handle the concatenation yourself. This really goes for anything where Salesforce provides us with standard logic they've built themselves. It saves us time, is probably better-written, and is almost certainly better-optimized.